# Syntax missing error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

trying to get to grips with javaScript and come across syntax missing error however it doesn't say what is missing it is just blank?

```
"Error= SyntaxError: Missing  before statement"
```

any help is appreaciated!

Code below:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
}
else if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
    if(choice2 === "paper") {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
    else {
        return "rock wins":
    }
};
}
```

"

Comment: May you post your code?

Comment: well, `SyntaxError`s are a bad thing, but usually it's a problem with the code, so good luck getting any help without code *sigh*

Comment: Yup just added it ^^

Comment: I suppose the syntax error message gave a line number, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the error message you get is worded like that, but the error is on this line:

```
        return "rock wins":
```

You've got a colon where you should have a semicolon.

Fix that and the code runs. (In Chrome, the error I get is about the colon being an unexpected token.)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
return "rock wins":
```

to:

```
return "rock wins";
```

(i.e. use a semi-colon rather than a colon to end the statement)